# Map Keys in QtCreator's Fakevim

Tags: qt-creator, fakevim

I'd like to know how it is possible to use

```
:map
```

in fakevim (qt),
and how to load a .vimrc file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `:map` in Qt Creator's fakevim mode, but I'd discourage you to load your real vim's `.vimrc` file, because the fake vim mode is pretty minimalist. You can mostly use `:set` and `:map`, but forget about advanced vim specific stuff or plugins.

You can enable reading of a fakevim's vimrc by setting the option in:

```
Tools > Options > FakeVim category > General tab
```

[image: screenshot]

there you can check:

```
Read .vimrc from location:
```

and specify the location in the text box next to it.

Comment: Thank you zmo, I had some conflict problems with keys already binding on QT Creator.
Anyway everythings work ok, but I cannot receive mapped keys list with :map

Comment: yup, as I said, this is _not_ vim, just a basic surrogate that's good enough!